# Is there a way to have a Progress Bar both progress and have the indeterminate animation?

Tags: android, progress-bar

For example:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated

The progress bar has it's progress increasing from 0 to 100 percent but it still has some animation to it.  This helps show the user something is still happening even if the bar is stopped at one point for a moment.

When I set the progress bar to indeterminate, it no longer shows the progress.

Is there a built in way to accomplish this or will I need to subclass ProgressBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to subclass ProgressBar.